# How to create a sequence of actions mid-expression in ReasonML (and avoid creating a tuple)?

Tags: control-flow, reason, k-combinator

I want to bail out of a function early, if given unsuitable arguments The imperative solution in Javascript is elegant:

```js
arg=>{
 if(arg>limit) return 42;
 //perform complex operations
 return x+y
}
```

ReasonML as a functional language has no `return`, thus I am stuffing everything into single expression:

```reasonml
arg=>{
    let helper=()=>{
        //complex operations here
        ; x+y
    }
    (arg>limit) ? 42 : helper()
}
```

Now, this works but instead of just returning 42 I want to stuff in `Js.Log("!CORNER CASE!")`. How can I do that? In C, I could write `(arg>limit) ? (Js_Log("..."),42) : helper()`, but in ReasonML this becomes a tuple and does not compile.

OCaml could do `begin printf "msg" ; 42 end`, but semicolon does not work for me in Reason: `(Js.log("TEST");42)` -- does not compile!

Alternatively, I need the K-combinator in ReasonML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with just using

```rust
if (arg > limit) {
  Js_Log("...");
  42
} else {
  //complex operations here
  x + y
}
```

but if you absolutely have to squeeze into a ternary conditional you can use curly braces to form a code block there too, and generally anywhere you can put an expression:

```rust
arg > limit ? {Js.log("..."); 42} : helper()
```

I would usually consider this a code smell though, but for quick debugging it can be handy.

Comment: To me, the if version is the stinky one, because of the moving indentation. The complex operations are stable code and should not travel because of the more change-prone entry conditions. However, thanks for support, I must have become lost in counting parentheses, because {a;b} was not compiling and I was not sure it is valid syntax. Now that I know it is, I massaged it into a working condition. The actual line reads: (ip>=max)? (ip>max+dmax)?0:{Js.log({j|ISPMAX=$ispmax!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!|j});ispmax}:(min>ip)?0:helper()